# Putting sanitiser in PVC bottles

Tags: safety

can I put hand sanitiser in PVC bottles or must the bottles be PET.  With the shortage of bottles I am keen to know if a 70% ethanol or isapropyl based sanitiser will distort or soften a PVC bottle in the short term or long term?

Comment: I can also obtain small  LDPE bottles (4)   Are these safe?

Answer (score 1):

A don't see major problems in storing it in a PVC bottle,   PVC is not soluble in ethanol, neither in isopropanol. However, in [this site](https://www.calpaclab.com/pvc-polyvinyl-chloride-chemical-compatibility-chart/) they rate isopropyl alcohol as A while ethanol as C (with possible swelling in the long term).